# Is this a mini computer, a novelty monitor or something else?

Tags: identify-this-computer

I saw this in the background of a video and I'm wondering what kind of device this is. It looks like a small pink CRT monitor with some keyboard-like buttons and was playing an animation.

[image: pink CRT monitor]

Comment: I'd say some modern device that is.

Comment: I think the pink colour is a clue. I never saw a machine room with pink cabs :-)

Comment: @another-dave Search Google Images for "PDP-11 front panel". But this is NOT one of those!

Comment: Proper 11's are magenta (and purple), not pink.

Comment: The absolutely square screen ratio (not 4:3) is also an indicator that it's not an old CRT.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've found it by looking up "miniature vintage computer." It's a modern portable speaker called [Ditoo](http://www.divoom.com/product/ditoo.html) <sup>([Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20200407222652/http://www.divoom.com/product/ditoo.html))</sup>.

Comment: The regular website loads much faster than Wayback http://www.divoom.com/product/ditoo.html

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, but Wayback is generally more reliable. If someone comes across this question in five years, there's a good chance Divoom won't still have the same product page up.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. I'm merely stating that the products website is much faster.